# How to make many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, many-to-many

can someone help me make many to many relationship?

```
CREATE TABLE Classes(
    id_classes Integer not null Primary Key,
    name Varchar(30) not null,
    start_day Date not null
 );

CREATE TABLE Students (
    id_students Integer not null Primary key,
    name Varchar(30) not null,
    surname Varchar(45) not null,
    birthDate Date not null,
    class Varchar(5) not null
);
```

How should i make many to many relationship now? 
Thank you.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with a junction table.  Here is a good structure for such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentClasses (
    id_studentclass int primary key,
    id_student int references student(id_student),
    id_class int references class(id_class),
    constraint unique unq_studentclasses_student_classes unique (id_student, id_class)  -- not sure if needed
);
```

Notes:

- I don't know if the unique constraint is appropriate.  A student could take a class multiple times.
- I think the id column for `classes` should be `id_class`, in the singular, because it refers to a single class.  Similarly for `id_student`.
- I added a primary key to the table.  In this case, you might have additional information about the relationship -- when did the student register?  what is the grade?
- All your id columns should be auto-generated, using `identity`, `auto_increment`, `serial`, or `generated always as`, depending on the database.
- `NOT NULL` is redundant in a `PRIMARY KEY` declaration.  Primary keys cannot be `NULL` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridge table which can represent many classes mapping to many students:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentClasses (
    id_classes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_students INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_classes, id_students)
)
```

Note that the primary key of this table is actually the composite of the ID fields for classes and students.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no database expert but I would suggest a Tuple (Bridge) table. This is a table that contains the Id of one entity mapped to the Id of another. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentsClasses (
FOREIGN KEY (studentId) REFERENCES Students(id_students)
FOREIGN KEY (id_classes) REFERENCES Classes(id_classes))
```

then create a one to many relationship between your students table to the strudents classes table and the same for classes.